# How do I 'declare' an empty bytes variable?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, byte, variable-assignment

How do I initialize ('declare') an empty `bytes` variable in Python 3?

I am trying to receive chunks of bytes, and later change that to a
utf-8 string.
However, I'm not sure how to initialize the initial variable that will
hold the entire series of bytes. This variable is called `msg`.
I can't initialize it as `None`, because you can't add a `bytes` and a
`NoneType`. I can't initialize it as a unicode string, because then
I will be trying to add `bytes` to a string.
Also, as the receiving program evolves it might get me in to a mess
with series of bytes that contain only parts of characters.
I can't do without a `msg` initialization, because then `msg` would be
referenced before assignment.
The following is the code in question

```
def handleClient(conn, addr):
    print('Connection from:', addr)
    msg = ?
    while 1:
        chunk = conn.recv(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        msg = msg + chunk
    msg = str(msg, 'UTF-8')
    conn.close()
    print('Received:', unpack(msg))
```

Comment: This is initialization, not declaration. Python doesn't have declaration of types.

Comment: would you say "initialization" or "instantiation"?  Perhaps both ... But as you say, definitely not "declaration"

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Just use an empty byte string, `b''`.

However, concatenating to a string repeatedly involves copying the string many times. A [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytearray), which is mutable, will likely be faster:

```
msg = bytearray()  # New empty byte array
# Append data to the array
msg.extend(b"blah")
msg.extend(b"foo")
```

To decode the byte array to a string, use `msg.decode(encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: You can also just keep the received chunks in a list, and join them at the end.

Comment: Even if the program weren't entirely I/O bound waiting on the socket, I can't imagine that the performance cost would actually matter anywhere.

Comment: From a quick test, with 1024 chunks of 1024 bytes, in 64-bit Python 3.3.1, `bytes` took 30.1ns, `bytearray` took 29.6ns, `join` took 29.9ns.

Answer (score 3):

`bytes()` works for me;

```
>>> bytes() == b''
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `msg = bytes('', encoding = 'your encoding here')`.

Encase you want to go with the default encoding, simply use `msg = b''`, but this will garbage the whole buffer if its not in the same encoding

Answer (score 1):

To allocate bytes of some arbitrary length do

```py
bytes(bytearray(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

> Blockquote
>   socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])
>   Receive data from the socket. The return value is a **string** representing the data received.
>   Blockquote
>   So, I think msg="" should work just fine:

```
>>> msg = ""
>>> msg
''
>>> len(msg)
0
>>>
```

Comment: You appear to be quoting [the Python 2.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv), but the question is about Python 3, [where `recv` returns `bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv).

Comment: The behaviour between Python 2 and 3 is indeed different. I just ported my code from Python 2 to 3 to get rid of the extra code related to unicode. I then ran into this difference, which is how I ended up asking this question.

Comment: Ooops... sorry didn't see python 3 on top :(